# Using Owin without Idenity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity, owin

I have an asp mvc application that requires very low level authentication and login functionality. The user has a unique 7 digit number in which they will enter to log into the application. Once authenticated they are able to edit an EF db. That's it!

Currently I am using a basic implementation of Owin to authenticate and sign in the user. Basically I have an input field where the user enters their number and then I look it up using EF, if I find the number I create a claim and sign them in.

I am quite new to this and I do not see the benefits of using the Asp Identity system as I do not need external login capability or registration functionality. Additionally I do not have user profiles. I simply need a way to check these numbers to identify the user is in a DB and then sign them in. So the questions are: is my implementation of only Owin valid? And why would I need the asp Identity framework here?

```
[HttpPost, AllowAnonymous, ValidateInput(true)]
        public ActionResult Index(employeePSDB lookUpEmployeeID)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                using (var db = new PsEntities())
                {
                    IEnumerable<employeePSDB> foundEmployeeInDb = db.employeePSDBs.Where(foundEmployee => lookUpEmployeeID.EmployeeNumber == foundEmployee.EmployeeNumber);


                    if (foundEmployeeInDb.Count() > 0)
                    {
                        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(new[] {
                            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, foundEmployeeInDb.First().EmployeeNumber.ToString())
                        }, "ApplicationCookie");

                        var contex = Request.GetOwinContext();
                        var authManager = contex.Authentication;



                        authManager.SignIn(identity);
                        return Redirect(GetRedirectUrl(lookUpEmployeeID.ReturnUrl));
                    }
                }
            }
  //user authN failed or ModelState is not valid
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Not in db");
        employeePSDB newLookUp = new employeePSDB
        {
            ReturnUrl = lookUpEmployeeID.ReturnUrl
        };
        return View(newLookUp);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am by no means an expert and perhaps someone can expand more on this, but your implementation is a valid cookie based authentication. The Asp identity framework or system is just there to help with the building and maintenance of your model. Using your own Entity Framework model is fine. Please see the below links for further research...

http://www.khalidabuhakmeh.com/asp-net-mvc-5-authentication-breakdown 
http://www.khalidabuhakmeh.com/asp-net-mvc-5-authentication-breakdown-part-deux

And to clear up any confusion:
http://brockallen.com/2012/06/04/membership-is-not-the-same-as-forms-authentication/